# Right approach for aggregating data from multiple tables in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, entity, projection

I have a Q&A section where each question and answer has a user profile card associated with it. It is very similar to how it is here on stack overflow. Data that makes up this user profile card is spread across multiple tables. I am fetching one or two columns from each of these tables. Now I am not sure what approach I should take to associate user profile card with each question and answer. Following are my thoughts

1. I cannot have a straightforward association in question and answer entity since user profile card itself is not a single entity but is an aggregate object
2. I have considered creating DTOs as projections to aggregate data for question and user profile card into one DTO like below

   ```
   @Query("select new com.QuestionDto(q.id, q.topic, q.views, ud.username, ur.points) from QuestionEntity q join UserDetails ud ON q.userId = ud.userId join userRanking ur ON ud.userId = ur.userId where q.id = :id")
   QuestionDto findQuestionDto(@Param("id") Long id);
   ```

The problem I see with this approach is there will be such DTOs for answer, comments etc as well. So whenever there is a change to user profile card I will need to make those changes to all the DTOs accordingly. Which will be a very poor design from code maintainability perspective.

3. Another approach is to aggregate user profile card data into a DTO of itself and then this DTO will be called from each question, answer etc. With this approach at least the logic for user profile card is at one place.

   ```
   @Query("select new com.UserProfileCard( ud.username, ur.points) from UserDetails ud join userRanking ur ON ud.userId = ur.userId where ud.userId = :id")
   UserProfileCard getUserProfileCard(@Param("id") Long userId);
   ```

But on the flip side If a question has 15 replies, that will lead to (1 + 15) queries for each user. From performance perspective I don't see this as very efficient.

What else? Is there any other approach I am missing that is good from code maintainability as well as performance perspective?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> 2. I have considered creating DTOs as projections to aggregate data for question and user profile card into one DTO like below

You can still use your option 2 while having a separate dto of UserProfileCard.

Package javax.persistance provides this feature of embedding a dto into another entity dto by using annotation javax.persistence.Embedded. The embedding dto class is annotated by javax.persistence.Embeddable. Your dto classes will look somewhat like below -

```
@Embeddable
public class UserProfileCard {

    private String username;

    private Integer points;
}

@Entity
public class QuestionDto {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String topic;

    private Long views;

    @Embedded
    private UserProfileCard userProfileCard;
}
```

And you can use the same query to fetch the QuestionDto -

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select q.id, q.topic, q.views, ud.username, ur.points from question_entity q join user_details ud ON q.user_Id = ud.user_Id join user_ranking ur ON ud.user_Id = ur.user_Id where q.id = :id")
QuestionDto findQuestionDto(Long id);
```

***** UPDATE *****

Avoiding code duplication in dao interface using a sql view for UserProfileCard and using it in all dependent queries.

```
String USER_PROFILE_CARD_VIEW = "select ud.user_id, ud.username, ur.points from user_details as ud join user_ranking as ur on ur.user_id = ud.user_id";

@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select q.id, q.topic, q.views, userprofilecard.* from question_entity q join (" + USER_PROFILE_CARD_VIEW +") as userprofilecard on userprofilecard.user_id = q.user_id where q.id = :id")
QuestionDto findQuestionDto(Long id);
```

Comment: But the problem is code duplication. I will have to do the same for other entities that need `UserProfileCard`. And future changes to `UserProfileCard` will create maintenance issues.

Comment: Now the code duplication is in dao interface only, which should be resolved by defining the sql view for UserProfileCard and using the same view in each of your dependent query.